# Google Sheet combining two/three sets of col and calculate unique values with each

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have the following

```
col1    col2    col3   col4
NY      sys1    DB1    4
CA      sys1    DB1    2
CA      sys1    DB1    1
MI      sys1    DB1    1
DC      sys1    DB2    2
MI      sys1    DB2    2
```

In google sheets I want the output to look like this. Note: records in DB1 need to be counted separately and DB2 separately, but unique within each DB, and output I don't want to repeat DB1 with each record, as all records in the next col are from DB1. Only display DB1 one and then when the DB changes, then display the new one once and display and count its own records

```
DB1    NY    4
       CA    3
       MI    1
DB2    DC    2
       MI    2
```

I tried the formula suggested but it keeps giving me parsing error not sure what I am doing wrong
[Here is what I a typing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XA89L.png)

My actual is as follows: Of course, col B is showing the same data in the snapshot, but since other values are way down so could not capture other different values. Please assume that Col B has different values.

[My actual data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5XN0.png)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({IF(COUNTIFS(
 QUERY(QUERY(A:D, "select C,A,sum(D) where A !='' group by C,A label sum(D)''", 0), "select Col1", 0), 
 QUERY(QUERY(A:D, "select C,A,sum(D) where A !='' group by C,A label sum(D)''", 0), "select Col1", 0), ROW(INDIRECT("F1:F"&COUNTA(
 QUERY(QUERY(A:D, "select C,A,sum(D) where A !='' group by C,A label sum(D)''", 0), "select Col1", 0)))), "<="&ROW(INDIRECT("F1:F"&COUNTA(
 QUERY(QUERY(A:D, "select C,A,sum(D) where A !='' group by C,A label sum(D)''", 0), "select Col1", 0)))))=1, 
 QUERY(QUERY(A:D, "select C,A,sum(D) where A !='' group by C,A label sum(D)''", 0), "select Col1", 0), ),
 QUERY(QUERY(A:D, "select C,A,sum(D) where A !='' group by C,A label sum(D)''", 0), "select Col2,Col3", 0)})
```

[image: 0]

---

EU syntax:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({IF(COUNTIFS(
 QUERY(QUERY(A:D; "select C,A,sum(D) where A !='' group by C,A label sum(D)''"; 0); "select Col1"; 0); 
 QUERY(QUERY(A:D; "select C,A,sum(D) where A !='' group by C,A label sum(D)''"; 0); "select Col1"; 0); ROW(INDIRECT("F1:F"&COUNTA(
 QUERY(QUERY(A:D; "select C,A,sum(D) where A !='' group by C,A label sum(D)''"; 0); "select Col1"; 0)))); "<="&ROW(INDIRECT("F1:F"&COUNTA(
 QUERY(QUERY(A:D; "select C,A,sum(D) where A !='' group by C,A label sum(D)''"; 0); "select Col1"; 0)))))=1; 
 QUERY(QUERY(A:D; "select C,A,sum(D) where A !='' group by C,A label sum(D)''"; 0); "select Col1"; 0); )\
 QUERY(QUERY(A:D; "select C,A,sum(D) where A !='' group by C,A label sum(D)''"; 0); "select Col2,Col3"; 0)})
```

Comment: Not working. Please see additional details added to the question